# SilverStripe 3: Image Object in controller function

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to write a function that displays images from the child pages on the Holder Page.

Because SilverStripe lacks some functionality on templates I figured it will be best to process it all in the controller.

There are some conditional statements I require which can only be done in php.

Controller.php

```
public function LatestWork() {

$works = WorkPage::get();

$i = 1;
$html = "";
foreach ($works as $work) {

  //Build the IMage Object so we can add it to the Work Object
  $ImageObj = File::get()->byID($work->FeaturedImageID);

  if ($this->is_odd($i)) {
    $html .= "<div class='row'>";
    $span = "span8";
  } else {
    $span = "span4";
  }
  $html .= "<div class = '$span'>" . $ImageObj->croppedImage(200,100)  . "</div>";
  if ($this->is_even($i)  || $i == $works->Count()) {
    $html .= "</div>";
  }
  $i++;
}

return $html;
}
```

When its processed in the view the divs and spans are there but the image is not. There are more conditions in the code but this is just the basic version.
It displays "Image_Cached" instead.

How can I make it display the image?

Comment: When you return $ImageObj->croppedImage(200,100) without the html or anything else eg: return $ImageObj->croppedImage(200,100) . " " it displays the image but as soon as you add anything it display Image_cache

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
public function LatestWork() {
    $rows=new ArrayList();
    foreach(WorkPage::get() as $workPage){
        if (!isset($bucket)){
              $bucket = new ArrayList();
              $bucket->push($workPage);
              $rows->push($bucket);
        } else {
              $bucket->push($workPage);
              unset($bucket);
        }
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Template:

```
<% loop LatestWork %>
    <div class="row">
    <% if Odd %>
        <div class="span-8">
            <% with $Me.First %>$FeaturedImage.CroppedImage(200,100)<% end_with %>
        </div>
        <div class="span-4">
            <% with $Me.Last %>$FeaturedImage.CroppedImage(100,50)<% end_with %>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="span-4">
            <% with $Me.First %>$FeaturedImage.CroppedImage(100,50)<% end_with %>
        </div>
        <div class="span-8">
            <% with $Me.Last %>$FeaturedImage.CroppedImage(200,100)<% end_with %>
        </div>
    <% end_if %>
    </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

would be the SS way to do it, so that your display logic doesn't clutter your controller

Comment: Hi JF,

Thanks again, As I was saying there is a bit more conditional logic in there where the SS way will not be able to do that's why I tried to do it with PHP.

If there is a SS way to Alternate the each row in the example I have here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098248/silverstripe-3-alternate-value-in-template-within-a-loop?rq=1 then that will be fantastic.

Comment: Span8 will have a larger image (Cropped) and Span4 will have a smaller image (Cropped). Every second row it will then switch to Span4 begin first then Span8 begin second

Comment: I have updated my response with what could be an approach to your question

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot and see how it goes. I've managed to do it all in the controller but it's very messy and I don't like creating the HTML in the Controller so hopefully your way is a lot better